# [API]Using Yelp API / PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, token, yelp

## First of all

- I want to use Yelp API with PHP.
- I want to get bearer access token, but can't.

## Code

The code below is one that I executed.

```
$url = "https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token";
$clientEncode = urlencode("?grant_type=client_credentials?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID?client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET");
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientEncode);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$array = json_decode($response, true);
$arrayVal = array_values($array);
$bearer_token = $array->access_token;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

And, the message below is the error message.

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:21:
class stdClass#1 (1) {
public $error =>
class stdClass#2 (2) {
public $code =>
string(16) "VALIDATION_ERROR"
public $description =>
string(165) "client_id or client_secret parameters not found. Make sure to provide client_id and client_secret in the body with the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type"
}
}
```

Maybe, the use of cURL is Okay, I think, but I don't know how to add parameters on the url.

Please teach me more good practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Hope This will work for you :)

```
<?
    $clientEncode = urlencode("https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $clientEncode);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $array = json_decode($response, true);
    $arrayVal = array_values($array);
    $bearer_token = $array->access_token;
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($array);
    echo '</pre>';

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering.
I can't think about "grant_type" posting into POSTFIELDS.
But, I resolved this problem by myself later by another way.